# pinch zoom with no javascript

Tags: html, css, pinchzoom

How can I achieve pinch-zoom functionality on a mobile device at a local level (i.e. not the *whole* page) without needing to use Javascript?  So far I can pinch-zoom the whole page through the use of the META viewport tag.

I have looked at CSS `touch-action: pinch-zoom` but bizarrely it doesn't do what its name suggests *at all* but apparently serves solely as a modified to other actions which have nothing to do with zooming.  However, [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) talks about how `touch-action` is supposed to work to allow native pinch zoom capability in the browser itself, which suggests that it should somehow be possible.

I have already tried to do this with IFRAMEs, but have apparently not hit on the right attributes needed to make it work:

pztest1.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Pinch-Zoom Test IFRAME contents</title>
</head>
<body>
  <H1>This is a test</H1>
  <p>Test, test, test.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This page *by itself* pinch-zooms, but only the entire page.  So I put the contents in an IFRAME in another page:

pztest2.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Pinch-Zoom Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>IFRAME test</h1>
    <iframe src="pztest.html" height="640" width="480">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am unable to pinch zoom at all in pztest2.html, neither in the body (which is expected) or in the IFRAME itself.  If I remove the meta tag from pztest2.html, then I can zoom the body of pztest.html and the iframe with it, but I am unable to just zoom the IFRAME itself, which is the goal.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to enable pinch zooming on only part of a page without javascript.

Comment: @sean well there *would* be if CSS vh/vw would actually be respected when pinch zooming on mobile.  it took me weeks to come up with that solution, it works in the desktop, and then i go and try it in a mobile browser only for it to be *completely ignored*! *stamps foot*

Comment: It's two different types of zooming though. On desktop, you're stepping up or down the zoom-level of the page, resetting the viewport, changing root font-size, etc. On mobile you're zooming in on the page like you do a photo—everything stays the same except gets bigger.

Comment: @sean apparently what the browser does is called "page zooming" and what the browser does (and only will do) is called "pinch zooming" and you're right, they are two separate things.